# Spring Security 3.0.3 and custom authentication processing filter

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I use Spring Security 3.0.3.RELEASE. I would like to create a custom authentication processing filter.

I have created a filter like this:

```
// imports ommited
public class myFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

I configures my `security.xml` in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <!--<session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>-->
        <custom-filter ref="ipFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" filters="none"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
        <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" always-use-default-target="true"/>
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login.jsp" invalidate-session="true"/>
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="ipFilter" class="myFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" />
</beans:beans>
```

Everything seems to be right, but when I try to access to protected pages insted of `myFilter.attemptAuthentication` called `myFilter.doFilter`.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course servlet container calls `MyFilter.doFilter` - after all, this is the [entry point](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) into the filter.

In your specific case, the servlet container is supposed to call `doFilter()` on [AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.htmlBlockquote), not on `MyFilter`.

`AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter()` in turn is responsible for calling `MyFilter.attemptAuthentication()`.

If that is not the case, maybe **you overrode** `doFilter()` in `MyFilter`? If yes, **better remove that** (or at least call `super.doFilter()`). See JavaDocs of [AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.htmlBlockquote) for more details.

**EDIT**: MinimeDJ clarified that everything is as I am suggesting above. In that case, I suggest to check the value of `filterProcessesUrl` property. From the [JavaDocs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.htmlBlockquote):

> This filter will intercept a request and attempt to perform authentication from that request **if the request URL matches the value of the filterProcessesUrl property**. This behaviour can modified by overriding the method requiresAuthentication.

So you can:

- either set the appropriate `filterProcessesUrl` value (usually something like `/j_spring_security_check`)
- or you can override `requiresAuthentication` method to always return `true`.

If you are still having problems then I suggest you take a debugger and step through spring-security (and your) code to see where exactly the issue occurs.

Comment: Hi Neeme, it is MyFilter. Everything in the code as you suggested, but somehow attemptAuthentication is not called... Anything else to check?

Comment: added some suggestions to the response

Comment: Ok, I manage to make everythinf work. I had to remove standard <http> config and config spring security via bean configuration. Thank you!